# Django return, Profile matching query does nor exit

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm working on an Instagram clone project as a beginner. And I didn't get this error. I imported the user
[The Profile class is created here, and it is successfully migrated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3vlG.png)

[and this is my views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXDfy.png)

someone please answers this where is my mistake?

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Where do you get this error? Profile matching query does not exist?

Comment: not "does nor exit", but "does not exists"...

Comment: not "does not exists" but "does not exist"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check in your database whether the profile of that user is created or not

Comment: Yeah, It's not there, but I try to create using superuser but it's not shown in that database.

Comment: Are you creating profile of superuser or other user using admin?